# Simple AJAX post not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I want to do a simple post using AJAX, my values that I want to post are correctly filled (I've check with alertboxes) but I can't have this working.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#envoyer").click(function(){
    var formname = $("#contact-form input[name=form-name]").val();
    var formemail = $("#contact-form input[name=form-email]").val();
    var formsubject = $("#contact-form input[name=form-subject]").val();
    var formmessage = $("#contact-form input[name=form-message]").val();
    alert(formname);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/index.php',
      data: {form-name : formname, form-email : formemail, form-subject : formsubject, form-message : formmessage},
      success: function(data)
      {
        alert("success!");
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Any idea about what I could do to make this work?

Comment: Do you have a comma (`,`)at the end of line that starts with `data:...`?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: I added the coma it's still not working, I'm lokking for the console output

Comment: Press the F12 key to get to your developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build your form data this way:

```
$(function(){
    $("#envoyer").click(function(){
        var FormData = form.serialize(); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/index.php',
            data: FormData,
            success: function(data) {
                alert("success!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```